# Calculation of the first time when a certain number of customers received service.

Tags: stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

**Problem**

Let us consider M/M/infinity queueing system. I would like to know the time distribution when $b$ customers received service. For this, I first showed that the distribution of the number of customers who received service until time $t$ ($M_t$) follows Poisson$(at+\exp(-at)-1)$. After that, I really have no idea how to calculate the pdf and the first-two moments of $T_b=\inf\{t: M_t\ge b\}$ from $M_t$.

How can I calculate the pdf of $T_b$ and its first-two moments (i.e. $E[T_b]$ and $E[T_b^2]$)?

**My idea**

Indeed, I have tried to use the optional stopping theorem. However, it seems to be difficult as I completely have no idea whether $M_t-E[M_t]$ is martingale or not. To my current feeling, $M_t-E[M_t]$ seems to be not a martingale. Then, how can we identify its pdf and moment...?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I have reformated your question and you might want to check it says what you intended. An $M/M/\infty$ process usually has two parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$: the rate of arrival and the rate of service.  $\lambda$ seems to be your $a$ but I do not see an equivalent of $\mu$.

Comment: Thanks for the kind reformulation, Indeed, I tried to identify the Tb under the assumption that λ=μ=a. Sorry for my native description of the problem.